# featherlight.js in Wordpress custom template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I made a custom template in wordpress, and everything works good, except featherlight.js, which worked in the non-wordpress version of the website, but doesn't work in the Wordpress template. All of the files are loaded successfully from the server. Right now, the images are opened in a new window, instead of the lightbox.

**featherlight.min.css** - loaded by `@import url('css/featherlight.min.css');`in the style.css file.

**featherlight.min.js** - loaded before the `</body>`tag - `<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/js/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Image example:

```
<a href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?> /img/ss/scrsht2-big.jpg" data-featherlight="image"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?> /img/scrsht2.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Have you trued "enqueuing" the scripts the "proper way" via: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script ? There could be a javascript conflict somewhere.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Just changed it to load with enqueue, along with jQuery 1.11.1. Now the console says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ", although jQuery file is loaded properly.

Answer (score 2):

As I can't post comment, below are the various points I'd thought may explain your issue.

1. Make sure you have enqueued your scripts the following way (and not forgotten jQuery):

   ```
   <?php

   function enqueue_my_scripts() {
       wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); //include jQuery version bundled with Wordpress in your page 
       wp_enqueue_style( 'featherlight', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/featherlight.min.css' );
       wp_enqueue_script('featherlight', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/featherlight.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );

   ?>
   ```
2. Check whether [jQuery version bundled with your Wordpress version](http://plugins.twinpictures.de/wordpress-jquery-versions/) suits your plugin.
3. The bundled jQuery is run in [no-conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/). Make sure the script that initialise your plugin (if there is one) can be read understood in this mode – basically use `jQuery` instead of `$` ([details here](http://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/)).
4. If your are using a child-theme, beware, `bloginfo('template_url')`, as  `get_template_directory_uri();`, return a link to the parent theme. In this case, use [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) instead.